# what api's are used for make game application in j2me

Tags: java, java-me

how to start to do game application in j2me? mostly what api's are used to develope game application in j2me. 
Try to give some materials or links to proceed game application?
i am newer to game application.give some basic guidelines about game application in j2me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1** [Getting Started With the MIDP 2.0 Game API](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/gameapi/)
**2** [j2me-game-canvas](http://www.academictutorials.com/j2me/j2me-game-canvas.asp)

Search through games and try to understand the concepts how it could be implemented , and try them on